# ActiveSheet.ShowAllData returns different results on 2 machines

Tags: excel, vba

I have some macro that filters all the data (250 rows) by one column, then deletes the data that is hidden after filtering.

Next step is unfiltering whole sheet using ActiveSheet.ShowAllData.

What's strange, on my machine after unfiltering my used range seems to be 200 rows (50 rows has been deleted).

However on another machine, with the same Excel version (Office365), after unfiltering and deleting 50 rows the visible range is 1,048,576 rows (what pretty much messes up further autofills etc.)

The code is as follows:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim iCntr As Long

Range("A:AI" & Lines).AutoFilter Field:=32, Criteria1:= _
    "2611"
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For iCntr = lastRow To 1 Step -1
    If Rows(iCntr).Hidden = True Then Rows(iCntr).EntireRow.Delete
Next

ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

Comment: `"A:AI" & Lines` is no valid address for a Range. What is `Lines`?

Comment: As  Pᴇʜ mention above "A:AI" & Lines is an invalid range for two reasons. After the first A you should enter the starting row. Second variable Lines is not declare.

Comment: Indeed it is not declared (I took it from another code) - but the autofiltering still works the same on both machines

Comment: It only works because `Lines` is an empty variable you need to remove it.

Comment: Changing Range("A:AI") didn't solve the issue

Comment: Sorry guys for disturbing - it occured that just before filtering I was changing to values empty column, whole column, which "enabled" all the available rows in the file. Nontheless thanks for support!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to collect all the rows that need to be deleted in a variable `RowsToDelete` and then show all data before you delete all the rows at once. Not sure if this finally fixes your issue but at least this is a lot faster than deleting each row after another.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DeleteAllHiddenRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ws.Range("A:AI").AutoFilter Field:=32, Criteria1:="2611"

    Dim RowsToDelete As Range

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To LastRow
        If ws.Rows(iRow).Hidden Then
            If RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set RowsToDelete = ws.Rows(iRow)
            Else
                Set RowsToDelete = Union(RowsToDelete, ws.Rows(iRow))
            End If
        End If
    Next iRow

    ws.ShowAllData
    RowsToDelete.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Indeed it works way faster than our code, but still I can scroll down to row 1,048,576 on one machine and on the the other one only to row 250 after deleting the rows (which is way more reasonable).

Comment: Actually you should always be able to scroll down to 1,048,576 because any Excel sheet has always the same amount of rows. If you remove rows it automatically adds new empty rows in the very end.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub clear_filter()
Dim sh As Worksheet



sh=activeworksheet
If sh.AutoFilterMode Then

 On Error GoTo 1
  sh.ShowAllData
    sh.AutoFilterMode = False
End If

1

MsgBox "Data filters cleared", vbInformation


    End Sub
```